# Shortcut for accessing the "method overview" in Xcode in a given class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can one access the following menu by using a shortcut in Xcode?

http://i.minus.com/j8OluIv8xj22Z.png

Comment: I find lots of goodies here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010560-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Xcode's Preferences > Key Bindings and assign a hotkey for the "Standard Editor > Show Document Items" command.

Comment: Great, it looks like it is bound to `CTRL + 6` by default.